# Save all user operation - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging

i'm starting with Spring. Now i'm writting simple project and have little question. How can i get list of all User operation? Exactly my point is that if you perform an operation in an application, I will be able to see the information about it in the right place applications. Is spring has some useful tools to create something like this? I will be grateful for helpful examples.

thank you for your help,

BR,
jerry

Comment: Show us something you have tried?

Comment: I tried to add the appropriate "prints" to methods, but I think it's not a good idea, so I I have nothing to show.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try **logging**. You can write a **Spring interceptor** and log every action i.e. request by the User there.

Here, are some tutorials: [Spring Interceptor](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/) [Logging](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/logging_with_log4j.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to just use the out-of-box Log4J in Spring Framework.

All you need to do is to configure the Log4j.properties file to outline the specific package name and everything from that level down will be logged. You can also specify the log level i.e. DEBUG or INFO or WARN or ERROR etc.

There is already few lines included in the log4j.properties files, i suppose the file is located in src/main/resources

if you use STS as your IDE, could log whatever you want by using the following code

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
logger.info("Welcome {}.", paramInBracket);
```

And In Log4J, include the logger settings for HomeController.class

```
<!-- Application Loggers -->
    <logger name="{package path that contains HomeController class}">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>
```

Hope this helps.